# Как заполнить столбец таблицы HTML из массива JS?

Tags: javascript, html

Подскажите пожалуйста порядок действий. Есть таблица "прайс-лист" в которой есть колонка "Цена". Над таблицей установлен `RadioGroup` с переключателем валют. Как с помощью скрипта `JS` менять цену в таблице в зависимости от выбранной валюты? Как это в целом организовать.
P.S. `JS` только начал изучать, поэтому еще не совсем разбираюсь.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ru">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Сервисный центр Ремонт+</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="E:\DIIT\ИНТЕРНЕТ(программирование)\ЛР2\styles.css">
    <script language="Javascript">
       // Курсы валют
       const uah = 10;
       const usd = 60;
       const rub = 1;

       // Все элементы 
       const elements = document.querySelectorAll('input[name="currency"]');
       // Кол-во элементов
       const len = elements.length;

       for (let i = 0; i < len; i++) 
       {
          elements[i].addEventListener('click', function() {
          setNewPrice(this.value);
          });
       }

       function setNewPrice(currency) 
       {
          const elements = document.getElementsByClassName('price');
          const len = elements.length;

          for (let i = 0; i < len; i++) 
          {
             const default_price = +elements[i].getAttribute('data-value');
             let new_price = 0;
             switch (currency) 
             {
                case 'UAH': new_price = default_price * uah; break;
                case 'USD': new_price = default_price * usd; break;
                case 'RUB': new_price = default_price * rub; break;
                default: new_price = default_price * rub; break;
             }
             elements[i].innerHTML = new_price;
          }
       }
</script>
</head>
<body>
   <div class="header">
   <center>
      <h1>Сервисный центр "Ремонт+"</h1>
      <nav>
         <a href="#about">О нас</a>
         <a href="#table_of_price">Расценки</a>
         <a href="#contacts">Контакты</a>
      </nav>
   </center>
   </div>
   <div class="main">

   <center>
      <div class="about">
      <h2>О нас</h2>
      <image src="about.png" class="img_about">
      <p>Наш сервисный центр предоставляет обширный профессиональный спектр услуг, качественная и своевременная сдача работы, особый подход к клиенту и его технике.
      Сервисный центр "Ремонт+" предоставляет систему лояльности и скидок для постоянных клиентов. Вы можете стать одним из них – экономить бюджет и драгоценное время.</p>
      <p>Для того чтобы закоментировать код HTML необходимо использовать тег <b> &lt!--...--&gt </b> </p>
      </div>
      <hr>
      <div class="table_of_price">
         <h2>Цены на услуги</h2>
         <!--<form action="main.js">-->
         Укажите валюту: <br>
         <div class="calculate">
            <input type="radio" name="currency" value="UAH">UAH
            <input type="radio" name="currency" value="USD">USD
            <input type="radio" name="currency" value="RUB" checked>RUB
         </div>
         </form>
         <table border = "1">
            <th>Наименование услуги</th>
            <th>Цена</th>
            <tr> <td colspan = "2", align="center", bgcolor="#D3EDF6">Диагностика устройства</td></tr>
            <tr><td>Глубокая диагностика телефона (в случае согласия на ремонт смартфона)</td> <td class="price" data-value="200">200</td></tr>
            <tr><td>Диагностика мобильного (в случае отказа от ремонта смартфона)</td> <td class="price" data-value="100">100</td></tr>
            <tr> <td colspan = "2", align="center", bgcolor="#D3EDF6">Установка программного обеспечения</td></tr>
            <tr><td>Установка антивирусного программного обеспечения</td> <td class="price" data-value="40">40</td></tr>
            <tr><td>Установка приложений мультимедиа</td> <td class="price" data-value="30">30</td></tr>
            <tr><td>Установка социальных сетей</td> <td class="price" data-value="15">15</td></tr>
            <tr><td>Установка любого приложения (на выбор клиента)</td> <td class="price" data-value="20">20</td></tr>
            <tr> <td colspan = "2", align="center", bgcolor="#D3EDF6">Ремонт/замена комплектующих</td></tr>
            <tr><td>Замена/ремонт дисплея телефона</td> <td class="price" data-value="300">300</td></tr>
            <tr><td>Замена/ задней крышки телефона</td> <td class="price" data-value="200">200</td></tr>
            <tr><td>Замена батареи мобильного телефона</td> <td class="price" data-value="200">200</td></tr>
            <tr><td>Замена/ремонт микрофона смартфона</td> <td class="price" data-value="100">100</td></tr>
            <tr><td>Замена/ремонт полифонического динамика смартфона</td> <td class="price" data-value="100">100</td></tr>
            <tr><td>Замена разговорного динамика телефона</td> <td class="price" data-value="150">150</td></tr>
            <tr><td>Ремонт фронтальной камеры телефона</td> <td class="price" data-value="300">300</td></tr>
            <tr><td>Ремонт основной камеры телефона</td> <td class="price" data-value="200">200</td></tr>
            <tr><td>Замена/ремонт виброзвонка смартфона</td> <td class="price" data-value="50">50</td></tr>
            <tr><td>Замена/ремонт датчика приближения телефона</td> <td class="price" data-value="250">250</td></tr>
            <tr> <td colspan = "2", align="center">Остальные разценки узнавайте у наших менеджеров по телефонам ниже</td></tr>
         </table>
      </div>
      </center>
      <hr>
      <h1 align="center">Преимущества ремонта именно у нас:</h1>
      <p text="14">Сотрудничество с нашим сервисным центром предполагает ряд преимуществ, которые получит клиент, а именно:</p>
      <div class="numeric_list">
         <ol>
            <li>Гарантию на работу сроком от 6 до 12 месяцев в зависимости от бренда и модели телефона (на китайские телефоны гарантия 6 месяцев);</li>
            <li>Лояльные цены на ремонт смартфонов;</li>
            <li>Оплата работы после качественного ремонта телефона;</li>
            <li>Оплата наличным и безналичным способом;</li>
            <li>Наличие восстребованных оригинальных запчастей на складе;</li>
            <li>Услуга срочного ремонта телефонов, подразумевающая восстановление гаджета за один рабочий день.</li>
         </ol>
      </div>
      <p><u>А также:</u></p>
      <div class="mark_list">
         <ul type="square">
            <li>Оплата наличным и безналичным способом;</li>
            <li>Помощь и консультации в настройке хранилищ ("облако") на телефонах IPhone, Xiaomi, Meizu и др.;</li>
            <li>Регистрация и настройка аккаунтов, установка полезных приложений.</li>
            <li>Консультации по эксплуатации и ремонту телефона и др.</li>
         </ul>
      </div>
      <hr>
      <div class="contacts">
         <center>
            <h2>Контакты</h2>
        </center>
        <p><strong>Адрес: </strong>г. Днепр, пр. Богдана Хмельницкого, 151</p>
        <p><strong>Телефон: </strong><a href="tel:+380565605656">+38 (056) 560-56-56</a></p>
        <p><strong>Время работы: </strong>Пн - Пт, с 09.00 до 19.00, Суббота - с 09.00 до 15.00</p>
        <p><strong>Em@il: </strong><a href="mailto:m@cto.com">m@cto.com</a></p>
      </div>
      <hr>
   </div>
   <div class="footer">
   <center>
        <p>© 2008-2019 Все права защищены.</p>
    </center>
   </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Сначала, ваши попытки

Comment: Я только сделал форму на HTML а дальше не знаю как сделать. Хранить цены в массиве, или считывать в скрипте цены в массив.

Comment: Для начало, вам необходимо привести таблицу с ценами (можно урезанную). Далее вам необходимо выбрать это таблицу (получить ссылку на коллекцию) через `document`. После пройтись по элементам коллекции. И всё это делать по событию, например изменения чекбокса.

Comment: Добавил фрагмент таблицы. Она состоит из двух столбцов. Как записать в массив только второй столбец (тот что с ценами)?

Comment: вечером отвечу)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Отдельно прокомментирую следующие строчки кода:

```
const len = elements.length;
```

Вычисляем количество элементов. Конечно, можно написать это прямо в `for` и движки, скорее всего, не станут вычилять количество элементов на каждой итерации, а сделают это один раз. Я просто привык это делать, так как не знаю как именно работает тот или иной движок.

```
const default_price = +elements[i].getAttribute('data-value');
```

Оператор `+` приводи к типу `Number`.

```js
// Курсы валют

const uah = 10;
const usd = 60;
const rub = 1;

// Все элементы 
const elements = document.querySelectorAll('input[name="currency"]');
// Кол-во элементов
const len = elements.length;

for (let i = 0; i < len; i++) {
  elements[i].addEventListener('click', function() {
    setNewPrice(this.value);
  });
}

function setNewPrice(currency) {
  const elements = document.getElementsByClassName('price');
  const len = elements.length;
  
  for (let i = 0; i < len; i++) {
    const default_price = +elements[i].getAttribute('data-value');
    let new_price = 0;
    
    switch (currency) {
      case 'UAH': new_price = default_price * uah; break;
      case 'USD': new_price = default_price * usd; break;
      case 'RUB': new_price = default_price * rub; break;
      default: new_price = default_price * rub; break;
    }
    
    elements[i].innerHTML = new_price;
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="calculate">
  <input type="radio" name="currency" value="UAH">UAH
  <input type="radio" name="currency" value="USD">USD
  <input type="radio" name="currency" value="RUB" checked>RUB
</div>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>Установка антивирусного программного обеспечения</td>
    <td class="price" data-value="40">40</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Установка приложений мультимедиа</td>
    <td class="price" data-value="30">30</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Установка социальных сетей</td>
    <td class="price" data-value="15">15</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Установка любого приложения (на выбор клиента)</td>
    <td class="price" data-value="20">20</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

> **UPD**
>   **1.** В цикле мы каждому элементу добавляем [слушателя](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) методом `addEventListener` на событие `click`. 
>   **2.** В `addEventListener` передаём два параметра: первый — тип события (`click`), а второй анонимная функция.
>   **3.** Как только мы кликнем по элементу (наши `<input>`), то сразу вызовется (отработает) наша анонимная функция, у которой контекст (`this`) будет элемент, на который кликнули. Анонимная функция вызовет функцию `setNewPrice` в которую мы передаём значение `<input>` (`UAH`, `USD`, `RUB`).
>   **4.** Строкой `function setNewPrice(currency)` мы объявили функцию, которая в качестве аргумента принимает **сurrency** ([валюта](https://translate.google.com/#view=home&op=translate&sl=en&tl=ru&text=currency)). Мы могли написать здесь любое слово, но для читаемости кода правльнее писать имя сущности, с которой будет работать наша функция.
>   **5.** Далее оператору `switch` передаём нашу переменную (аргумент функции). Так как мы знаем, что должно придти (значение наших `<input>`), то мы эти значения указываем в `case`. Но если придёт что-то, что мы не ожидаем, то сработает `default`.

Comment: спасибо, а зачем функции setNewPrice параметр currency? и что означает эта строка  elements[i].addEventListener('click', function() {
    setNewPrice(this.value);
  }?

Comment: Вам бы основы почитать. И воспользоваться гугл переводчиков. Сейчас добавлю комментарии.

Comment: Я пишу в NotePad++ и он не хочет распознавать атрибут data-value

Comment: 1. А при чём тут редактор? И что значит, не хочет распознавать `data-value`?

Comment: Я полностью выложил код HTML, вроде все правильно сделал, а понять все равно не могу почему не работает "конвертер валют"

Comment: @КириллНенахов так вы код (`js`) перенесите перед `</body>`

Comment: А он не обязательно должен быть в <head>?

Comment: @КириллНенахов не обязательно. А проблема у вас в том, что скрипт отработал до того как создалось дом дерево. И консоль смотрите.